# Ayuda ListView Flutter Json

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

soy nuevo en esto de Flutter y tengo una duda de como cargar datos de un JSON a mis ListView , hasta ahora tengo esto , es todo lo que he podido encontrar en la RED y guiandome en tutoriales y todo eso

```
import 'dart:convert' show jsonDecode;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List userMap;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var userResponde = await http.get(
        "https://wixitools.000webhostapp.com/hiperbarica/Ajax/Aj_Referido.php?Requerimiento=CargarDoctorReferidowebservice");

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(userResponde.body);

    userMap.forEach((key, value) {
      print(value);
    });

    

    return "Success!";
  }

  void initState() {
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: userMap == null ? 0 : userMap.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var user = userMap[index];
          return new Container(
            child: new Text('$user'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

y mi JSON luce asi tal cual, es un JSON hecho en GET aunque medio extraño pero si logro traer todos los values en un PRINT al momento de ejecutar a aplicacion

```
{
  "0": {
    "0": "1",
    "1": "DOCTOR 1",
    "id": "1",
    "datos": "DOCTOR 1"
  },
  "1": {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "DOCTOR 2",
    "id": "2",
    "datos": "DOCTOR 2"
  },
  "2": {
    "0": "6",
    "1": "DOCTOR 3",
    "id": "6",
    "datos": "DOCTOR 3"
  }
}
```

en el print que mando si me retorna los valores del json pero no se porque no cargan en el ListView

Answer (score 1):

Cuando trabajas con una clase con `StatefulWidget` siempre que hagas cambios es necesario llamar a la función  `setState(() {});` para redibujar los cambios.
En tu caso has creado dos variables `userMap` y lo que deberías es tener únicamente una instancia y ha esta añadir los elementos del mapa.

```
 List usersList = [];

  void getData() async {
    var userResponde = await http.get(
        "https://wixitools.000webhostapp.com/hiperbarica/Ajax/Aj_Referido.php?Requerimiento=CargarDoctorReferidowebservice");

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(userResponde.body);
    setState(() {
      userMap.forEach((key, value) => usersList.add(value));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: usersList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var user = usersList[index];
          print(user);
          return new Container(
            child: new Text(user['id']),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```